# Does the infini-lift allow you to go down just 1 level?

Tags: tiny-tower

I currently have the gold elevator in tiny tower. When I accidentally go 1 level over my destination I tap the down button as quickly as I can but it still goes down 2 levels. I'm just wondering if the final elevator fixes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed travel between individual floors with the Infini-Lift Lightspeed, it just takes a very light touch. I usually tap the up or down button instead of pressing and holding when I need to travel a short distance.